# Is "broadcast-address" necessary in dhcpd.conf?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

Or, more generally, is it required to specify the broadcast address that a client should use when a DHCP server is assigning an address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Clients default to using the highest address in the subnet if a broadcast address is not specified.

Remember to keep that address out of the dhcp pool.